# Как сделать, чтобы скрипт возвратил строку?

Tags: скрипт, html, perl

Всем привет!
Значит пример, на странице отобразим картинку с помощью скрипта, в скрипте пишем:

```
print "Location: <адрес нашей картинки>\n\n";
```

в html:

```
<img src=".../НашСкрипт.cgi?<Какие то параметры>">
```

в результате на странице появится наша картинка(простейший счетчик так работает). А мне нужно что бы вместо картинки скрипт вернул строку, "1.23" например(в зависимости от переданных ему параметров). Что то вроде: return "1.23"; Т.е. есть например тэг:

```
<b>Что прописать в скрипте и как его отсюда вызвать, что бы здесь появилось - 1.23</b>
```

Суть в том что страницу делать динамической и полностью выводить скриптом не желательно, равно как и вносить еще какие то изменения в html-код. Сейчас на странице так и прописано:

```
<b>1.23</b>
```

Мне нужно эти 1.23 менять скриптом. Надеюсь вопрос понятен. Спасибо!

Comment: не понятен вопрос. вы либо делаете страницу динамической, либо нет. html - не динамический язык. можно конечно с пом-ю js какие-то параметры выставить но по-моему вы просто не понимаете чего хотите.

Comment: не делаю динамической. В примере с картинкой показал как по передаваемым через параметры условиям скрипту выводить ту или иную картинку на страницу. Мне вместо картинки нужен текст.
Может так нельзя просто?

Comment: @Alex вы понимаете семантическую разницу между фразой "динамическая страница" и "статическая страница" ? помедитируйте просто минут 10 на эту тему.

Comment: Проделайте пример с картинкой на статической странице. Удивитесь.

Comment: удивлюсь чему ? тому что картинка генерится perl ? у вас три варианта:
генерировать весь ответ  с пом-ю perl
генерировать запрос с пом-ю ajax 
генерировать запрос с пом-ю iframe.

Answer (score 1):

В скрипте написать:

```
print("Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n");
print("1.23");
```

На странице использовать [SSI](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSI_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29):

```
<!--#include virtual="script.cgi"-->
```

Comment: SSI! Думал про это! Спасибо!
А без этого никак? )

Comment: зачем SSI если там и так perl есть ?

Comment: dionys, я просто не уверен есть ли поддержка SSI...

Comment: @eicto, потому что есть статическая страница и в неё надо добавить динамические данные.

Comment: @Alex, надо проверить. Если нет SSI, то будут другие решения.

Comment: @dionys SSI делает страницу динамической, вы бредите

Comment: @eicto, пойдите-ка с незнакомыми людьми разговаривать поучитесь. Потом возвращайтесь, обсудим решение.

Comment: @dionys пойдите-ка сначала поучите теорию, а потом обсуждайте. то что SSI имеет более простой синтаксис чем perl/php не делает его неинтерпретируемым на стороне сервера языком.

Answer (score 1):

```
dancer -a MyWeb::App
cd MyWeb-App

C:\TCPU59\utils\job\05062013\dance\MyWeb-App>bin\app.pl
[16132]  core @0.000008> loading Dancer::Handler::Standalone handler in c:/Dwimperl    /perl/site/lib/Dancer/Handler.pm l. 46
[16132]  core @0.000229> loading handler 'Dancer::Handler::Standalone' in         c:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Dancer.pm l. 462
>> Dancer 1.3092 server 16132 listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
== Entering the development dance floor ...
```

ctrl-C

добавляем в bin\app.pl

```
#!C:\Share\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe
use Dancer;
use MyWeb::App;

get '/hello/:name' => sub {
    return "Why, hello there " . params->{name};
};

dance;
```

запрашиваем в браузере
http://localhost:3000/hello/bob
получаем
Why, hello there bob
правим как у Вас в примере

```
#!C:\Share\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe
use utf8;
use Dancer;
use MyWeb::App;

get '/hello/:name' => sub {
    return "<b>Что прописать в скрипте и как его отсюда вызвать, что бы здесь появилось - ".params->{name}."</b>";
};

dance;
```

запускаем

```
http://localhost:3000/hello/1.23
```

видим:

```
Что прописать в скрипте и как его отсюда вызвать, что бы здесь появилось - 1.23
```

p.s.1 текст в скрипте должен быть в кодировке utf-8

p.s.2 http://www.perldancer.org/quickstart

Comment: Или Mojolicious::Lite